# Printing Search Results based on search keyword in Ruby Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am very new stackoverflow. So pardon me if I not asked question in right way.
I just started exploring Selenium WebDriver with Ruby.

My problem is as below:

I am navigating to a site(https://www.upwork.com) and entering search keyword(eg:Selenium) in search text box  and then I click on Search button. Once I got the Search Results, I am parsing all the search results.

Now I want to print all the names having my search keyword as their skills and I also want to print all names who do not have search keyword as their skills.I tried to do something like this.How can I handle this?

**Note: I can use only selenium-webdriver gem**

```
def freelancers_having_skills(skills)
   sleep(5)
   @allDetails=@driver.find_elements(FREELANCERS) #Capturing all the search results.
   @allDetails.each do |item|
      temp=item.text
      if(temp.include?skills)
         temp.each_char {
          |c| if (c!='\n')
                print c
              else
                break
              end
          break
         }
         puts
       end
     end
   end
```

Search Results page is like below.

[Search Results Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXbYM.png)

Comment: I am getting stuck on "I am not robot" screen. Can you tell me how to overcome that?

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me when you are getting "I am not robot" screen? I didnt face that issue